# Why my startup class in not getting invoked while hitting the URL?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

here is my Azure function which receives a request from http trigger and writes the received data to mongodb. Can you pls help me to figure out why my startup class is not getting invoked on sending data via using Azure function URL? below is the detailed code.
Note: I have all the necessary packages.

```
[assembly : FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace ItemApp_Azurefunction
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureDatabse(builder);
        }



        private static void ConfigureDatabse(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MongoConnectionString");
            string databaseName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MongoDatabase");
            builder.Services.ConfigureMongoDB(connectionString, databaseName);
        }
    }
}

 public static class DatabaseConfigurationcs
    {
        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureMongoDB(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, string database)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(v => 
            { 
                return new MongoClient(connectionString); 
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IMongoDatabase>(v => v.GetRequiredService<IMongoClient>().GetDatabase(database));

            services.AddScoped<ItemHandler>();

            return services;
        }
    }
  
  
  public static class Create
    {
        [FunctionName("Create")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                ActionRequest data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActionRequest>(requestBody);

                await ActionHandlerExtension.CreateHandler(data);

                var result = "Product created.";
                return new OkObjectResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Prduction could not be created. Here is the detailed error description : \n {ex.Message}");
            }
            
        }
    
     public static class ActionHandlerExtension
    {
      public async static Task CreateHandler(ActionRequest actionRequest)
        {
            //var request = ProductToActionExtension.ToModel(); 
            var request = actionRequest.ToModel();
            ItemHandler handler = new ItemHandler();
            await handler.Create(request);
        }
    }
    
    
     public class ItemHandler
    {
        private IMongoClient _client;
        private IMongoDatabase _database;  
 
        public ItemHandler(IMongoClient mongoClient, IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase) 
        {
            _client = mongoClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mongoClient));
            _database = mongoDatabase ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mongoDatabase)); 
        }

        public ItemHandler() { }
        public async Task Create(ProductModel action)
        {
            //var client = new MongoClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MongoConnectionString"));
            //var MongoDb = client.GetDatabase(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MongoDatabase"));
            var collection = _database.GetCollection<ProductModel>(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MongoDBCollection")); 

            IndexKeysDefinition<ProductModel> indexKeys = "{ No : 1 }";
            var indexModal = new CreateIndexModel<ProductModel>(indexKeys);
            await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModal);
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(action);
        }
}
```

I try to send data through the Azure function URL and when I hit then I get the error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

because this constructor is not getting invoked which is supposed to be invoked via startup class.

```
public ItemHandler(IMongoClient mongoClient, IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase) 
     {
         _client = mongoClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mongoClient));
         _database = mongoDatabase ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mongoDatabase)); 
     }
```

since I am beginner without using startup class my code was working but now I want to implement startup class and I ended up with this error.

Comment: What version of Azure Functions are you using?

Comment: Azure function v4.

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred these links [Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/introduction) ,  [MongoDB for.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-cli%2Cwindows#get-an-item) and thank  for your comment @StephenCleary

```cs
[FunctionName("Create")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                ActionRequest data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActionRequest>(requestBody);

                await ActionHandlerExtension.CreateHandler(data);

                var result = "Product created.";
                return new OkObjectResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Prduction could not be created. Here is the detailed error description : \n {ex.Message}");
            }
            
        }
```

**with items:**

```cs
var newProduct = new Product(
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                "gear-surf-surfboards",
                "Yamba Surfboard",
                12,
                false
            );

            await _products.InsertOneAsync(newProduct);
            var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Name, "Yamba Surfboard");
            var product = await _products.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
           log.LogInformation("Single product:");
            log.LogInformation(product?.Name);
            var productsFilter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Category, "gear-surf-surfboards");
            var products = await _products.Find(productsFilter).ToListAsync();
            log.LogInformation("Multiple products:");
            foreach (var prod in products)
            {
                log.LogInformation(prod.Name);
            }

            return new OkResult();
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]